# Edit boundaries in a map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a map with `ggplot2`. So far I am happy with my plot but I was wondering whether it is possible to edit the boundaries that separate each of the regions within the map. I know that adding `geom_path()` you can explicitly incorporate them but I have not figured out how to edit the level of thickness. Is anyone familiar with how to do this? Many thanks in advance.

The code I have used is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ex_sector = ggplot(data_mapping, aes(long, lat, group=group, fill = entry_cat)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Greens") + geom_polygon()  + geom_path(colour = "black")
 ggsave("test_fill.png", ex_sector, scale = 0.5)
```

An the output is:

[image]

Comment: add `size` to `geom_path`? e.g. `geom_path(colour = "black", size = .5)`

Comment: Great, that´s fine. Many thanks @beetroot.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible answer? Adding a `color` argument to geom_path may be the answer. If not, try adding to to geom_polygon. `geom_polygon(color = alpha("black", 1/2), size = .5))`